# Django structure with directories don't load views

Tags: python, django

I'm coming from the larvae on Django and I have a problem on this side and I can't say 100% of the documentation that I understand exactly the structure.
Do I have to make a directory for each part of the application, for example?
For example for the user a special directory, for the management of the application another one and so on?
Or can I have a main application like I did acm and have in it a folder view with several views.py and import them in urls?
Because I can't do that, I get an error.

For example this is my structure
[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySvDx.png)

This is the error
`AttributeError: module 'main.views' has no attribute 'pages_views'`

Url function from main

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import include
from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.pages_views.index, name='index'),
]
```

```
AttributeError: module 'main.views' has no attribute 'pages_views'
```

And url acces from project_management (core app I think)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import include
from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('main.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
]
```

Comment: Can you show the contents of your `main/views.py`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have an issue in your structure.
You should have something like this:
First in the urls of your project.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

`accounts.urls` redirects the request to an app. In each app folder, you create a "urls.py" folder, with following structure:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views as views

app_name="accounts"

urlpatterns = [
    path('new_user/', views.UserRegistrationView.as_view(), name="new_user"),
    path('change_password/', views.change_password, name='change_password'),
]
```

the `app_name` helps the urls conf at root to fetch the correct app.
Either, to make it simple, your `index`view should be directly located in the views.py.
If you really want to separate the concerns, you can create an app, which will be used for the general purpose views.